# I need to make a map (literally not the function) in which i should print a 20*20 map with pluses(+) but mark some of the coordinates

Tags: python

I need to make a map (literally not the function) in which I should print  a 20*20 map with pluses(+) but mark some of the coordinates which are inputs with #

first, I ask how many coordinates the user wants to give me
second, I get the coordinates and print the map with said coordinates marked on it

e.g. :
input:

```
2
(10,11)
(10,12)
```

output :

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - ## # + + + + + + +
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

```
c= ( 10 , 11)
a=c\[0\]
b=c\[1\]


for  y  in range (20):
    if y == a :
        for x in range (20):
            if x==b:
                print('#' , end= ' ') 
            else :
                print('+' , end = ' ')
    else:
      for x in range (20):
            print('+' , end= ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: You need to share the expected output indeed, we don't know what does the coordinates represent now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are there dots in the expected output? You only spoke of `+` and `#`. Why the expected output only has one `#`, while the input specifies two pairs of coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
from typing import List

ROWS = COLS = 20

# Define a function to create rows
def create_row(num_cols: int, default_char: str = "+")->List[str]:
    return [default_char for i in range(num_cols)]

# Define a function to create the map using function for row creation
# Make the arguments keyword only, it does matter which int is rows, which is cols (as long as your matrix is not necessarily n x n, but n x m (in general)
def create_map(*,rows:int, cols:int, default_char:str = "+")->List[List[str]]:
    char_map = []
    for i in range(rows):
        char_map.append(create_row(num_cols=cols, default_char=default_char))
    return char_map

# Create the map
plus_map = create_map(rows=ROWS, cols=COLS)

# This is just an example of user input coordinates
hashtag_coordinates = [(1,2), (3,4)] # I'll leave this part for you, populate it as you wish (using input function or whatever, file reading etc.), just keep it in a form of list of tuples

# Substitute the default "+" with "#" for user input coordinates
for x,y in hashtag_coordinates:
    plus_map[x][y] = "#"

# Print your map row by row
for r in plus_map:
    print(r)
```

- add docstrings, docstrings are cool...
- think of good variable names, those above are ok'ish, probably can be better / more descriptive
- [OPTIONAL] wrap the substitution of "+" into "#" in another function
- [OPTIONAL] write your own print function if the output is not what you expect it to be
- do not name variables "a", "b", cause that means nothing
- if you repeat the same magic number in a few places like `in range(20)` and so on name it, all caps if it's a constant